# Spin velocity in table tennis

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, projectile, aerodynamics

I have read on papers that argued, when flying, we have constant spin velocities $\omega_x, \omega_y, \omega_z$, that primarily depend on the initial spin setting e.g., topspin, bottom spin and sidespin.

Taking the following coordinate setting. Then topspin and bottom spin affect the spin velocity $\omega_w$, and sidespins affect the $\omega_y$ component.

My question is what about $\omega_z$?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top/bottom spin rotates as if the ball were rolling toward/away from you, and sidespin rotates about a vertical axis as if the ball were a top. Rotation about the third axis (which extends in a line directly away from you) can be called cork or corkscrew spin. It won't affect the trajectory of the ball as much as other types of spin, but can cause an unexpected bounce.

Comment: oh thanks! Do you happen to know whether there are bounds on the spin velocity, for example for each component $\omega_x, \omega_y, \omega_z$? Thanks!

Comment: @apieceofsomething Table tennis balls have been clocked spinning at 9000 RPM. The only theoretical upper bound would be the spin rate at which the ball tears itself apart. You could align the spin with any axis you choose, there's nothing specific to any directional component.